# Is there some authority files about instruction `jmpi`

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86

I am learning how Linux works. I have encountered a strange assembly language instruction, `jmpi`. I can find some explanation at various websites, but strangely I can't find it in assembly language books, including the [*Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual*](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html). I have searched the book, but it doesn't contain the instruction `jmpi`. I think the Intel manual should be the the most authoritative book on Intel assembly language. So it is very strange.

My question is: is there some book or authoritative files which document this instruction?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/as86 explains it, possibly?

Comment: Also, I think you may want to try Stack Overflow for questions actually about assembly language. If the moderators want to, they'll move the question for you—you don't need to do anything.

Comment: The Linux kernel uses the AT&T syntax (not the bletcherous intel one), and that means that for many instructions modifiers are appended to the instruction, not inferred from the arguments. I've searched (not too hard, mind you) for x86 (and x86_64) assembly tutorials in AT&T syntax, and came up empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several `JMP` instructions in the Intel processor instruction set. They have the same intended result but differ by the type of the operand they take: an 8-bit constant, a 16-bit constant, a 32-bit constant, a value specified indirectly; also is it a relative or an absolute jump. See the table from p.854 of the Architecture manual

```
Opcode Instruction  Description
------+------------+----------------------------
EB cb  JMP rel8     Jump short
E9 cw  JMP rel16    Jump near, relative
E9 cd  JMP rel32    Jump near, relative
FF /4  JMP r/m16    Jump near, absolute indirect
FF /4  JMP r/m32    Jump near, absolute indirect
FF /4  JMP r/m64    Jump near, absolute indirect
EA cd  JMP ptr16:16 Jump far, absolute
...
```

They are treated differently as a legacy of different memory models supported at different stages of the architecture development.

Many assemblers introduce additional mnemonics to make the assembly code more readable. So in `as86` the `JMPI` instruction refers to a near `JMP` it can be either absolute, or relative, but should always stay within a code segment, the *intrasegment jump*. The `as86` is the only authoritative reference.